# How can I get the value from an animated or interpolated value in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-animated

Short answer is: with `addListener`.
Every animated variable has addListener() method accessible. Right?
We should NOT access it from `__getValue()`.

---

I was struggling to get the interpolated value (number) out of this const:

```
const interpolatedvalue = this.state.myanimvalue.interpolate({...})
```

I wanted to get the numeric value out of this `interpolatedvalue`. I was trying to use __getValue(), but I realized I should not do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Updated

The right way of getting the value for an animated value is with a listener.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.5/animatedvalue#addlistener

Because the official docs say:

> addListener(...) Adds an asynchronous listener to the value so you can observe updates from animations. This is useful because there is no way to synchronously read the value because it might be driven natively.

If the animation is driven by the native layer, we can not really get it synchronously. So let's always use `addListener(value => {/*our logic to use value*/})`.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply access the value as `console.log(interpolatedValueY.__getValue())`

Comment: It seems it does not work if userNativeDriver is true.

Comment: @AlexandreLage, you sure it's not working? Because I used the same procedure with ```useNativeDriver = true``` and it works

Comment: @AlexandreLage, please share a snack too, if possible

Comment: @kreysix in my case also not working when useNativeDriver=true of find some solution please help me with that

Comment: @ParagJain can you share some piece of code so we can help you better?

Comment: @ofundefined sure  :below is code i am using                                                                                            Animated.decay(this.state.animation, {
      velocity: Direction,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start()                                                                                                                     and   "this.rotateInterPolate.__getValue() is how i am taking value but when i comment useNativeDriver it works fine and when it is true it is not giving proper result giving 0 only

Comment: Oh, just to make sure, 
this.rotateInterPolate is different to this.state.animation, right?

Comment: @ParagJain I have just updated my answer. So you can follow the right way. We should not really use __getValue()

Answer (score 0):

Attempting this in 2022, RN .70.5, adding an event listener for `interpolatedValueY` and then calling `interpolatedValueY.__getValue()` outside of the event listener should give you the updated value while `useNativeDriver` is set to true. Without the event listener, `interpolatedValueY.__getValue()` returns 0 no matter the actual animation value.